# how to create a new apex class in enterprice edition

Tags: salesforce

Hi i am lagging in this point so kindly let me know,how to create a new apex class in enterprice edittion or how to enable new button for apex class in enterprice eddition.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot create classes directly in enterprise edition, you need to create the classes and their tests in either a sandbox or developer edition account, and then deploy them to the enterprise edition login. See http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/App_Logic for more info.

Answer (score -3):

You mean that "*new*" button in "*Setup-> App Setup -> Develop -> Apex classes*" menu is disabled for you?

Please go to your Profile page (can be accessed for example by clicking the profile name in "*My Personal information*") and search on the page for "*Author Apex*" permission. This checkbox must be ticked if you want to be a developer.

If it's not checked - ask your admin for either ticking it for your profile (will impact all users that have same profile!) or assign a new profile for you.

Once you'll get the class creation from GUI working you can move on to slightly advanced topic of developing with Force.com Eclipse IDE (*App Setup->Develop->Tools*)

Comment: You can't create classes directly in EE, they need to be deployed along with their tests.

Comment: I misunderstood the question, didn't think OP was really trying to develop directly in production environment.